# CSS loads doesn't affect DOM

Tags: html, css

For some reason this CSS does not affect the HTML. On my website when I debug it, it says the CSS has loaded, but in the Styles pane it doesn't show up.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/master/dist/hamburgers.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="hamburger" type="button">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
    </button>
</body>
```

Comment: try using a relative url instead of an absolute one

Comment: i think you should clear browsing history from your system, hopefully it will work

Comment: @MdAman Still doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the url like below!

**Reason (Courtesy of [Mr.Lister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016716/mr-lister)):**

> The first link is a text file (type text/plain) which is not
>   recognisable as a stylesheet!

**Before:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/master/dist/hamburgers.css">
```

**After:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/master/dist/hamburgers.css">
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/master/dist/hamburgers.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="hamburger" type="button">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
    </button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this normally the git style link you added will not work as a cdn link. So use rawgithub.com domain to retrieve your css file.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgithub.com/jonsuh/hamburgers/master/dist/hamburgers.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="hamburger" type="button">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
    </button>
</body>
```